# can we send '%' symbol in request parameter value in url

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I tried to send "abc%yun" value in the request parameter but got an error as :
"message": "The request is not valid. Please check your parameters. (Invalid encoded sequence "%yun")".

So can we send "%" in the request parameter or not?

Comment: You should URL-encode parameters before you put them in the URL.

Comment: This is not a Java, Spring, Spring-Boot or Spring-MVC question.  It is about URLs.

Answer (score 0):

The `%` character is *special* in the URL encoding scheme, and as such needs itself to be encoded to be included in a URL parameter.

The `%` character is represented by `%25` in this scheme. Your example would then be `"abc%25yun"`.

[Here](https://www.urlencoder.org/) is one of many websites that allow you to encode values interactively. And [an article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Answer (score 0):

The % used for encoding the URL.
For example if you passing any request Param value with space then it will encoded with %20

```
URL - http://localhost/home?Param=sample one
```

It will encoded as below. The space replaced with %20.

```
URL - http://localhost/home?Param=sample%20one
```

While doing the encoding and decoding you have to use same standard format like UTF-8